# How to tell the network usage in linux without installing any new tool?

Tags: unix

I am doing a load test on a Unix machine and I want to see if my machine's configuration is limiting the number of requests I can make at a time.

I can find memory and CPU usage easily.

How do I find out the network usage without installing any new tool like iftop?

I do not have the ability to install new applications on the Unix machine.

I am using the following Linux version:-
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.5 (Maipo)

Comment: top, free, ip....

Comment: `netstat -s` will give you exhaustive information.